# Prove $\sqrt{a+1}+\sqrt{b+1}+\sqrt{c+1}\le 1+2\sqrt{a+b+c+abc}.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> **Question.** If $a,b,c\ge 0: ab+bc+ca=1.$ Prove that
> $$\sqrt{a+1}+\sqrt{b+1}+\sqrt{c+1}\le 1+2\sqrt{a+b+c+abc}.$$
> The problem was posted [here.](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6t243f6h3188980_abbcca1)

A trouble here is occuring equality: $(a,b,c)=(0,1,1).$
I've tried some approach based on it without success.

1. Since $abc\ge 0,$ we just need to consider $$\sqrt{a+1}+\sqrt{b+1}+\sqrt{c+1}\le 1+2\sqrt{a+b+c},$$which is already wrong at $a=b=1/2.$
2. Mixing variables technique.

WLOG, assume that $a=min\{a,b,c\}.$ Now, denote $f(a,b,c)=1+2\sqrt{a+b+c+abc}-\sqrt{a+1}-\sqrt{b+1}-\sqrt{c+1} .$

It's obvious that $f(a,b,c)\ge f(0,b,c).$ Hence, we'll prove $f(0,b,c)\ge 0.$

It turns out $$2\sqrt{b+\frac{1}{b}}-\sqrt{b+1}-\sqrt{\frac{1}{b}+1}\ge 0,$$which is smooth.

I'm not sure that $f(a,b,c)\ge f(0,b,c)$ is enough to give a full proof. Hope you point out it more clearly.

3. Jichen lemma

Put $(a+1,b+1,c+1,1,a+b+c+abc,a+b+c+abc)\rightarrow (x_1,x_2,x_3,y_1,y_2,y_3).$

We'll check three following inequalities $$2\le a+b+c+2abc \tag{1}$$
$$\sum_{cyc}(a+1)(b+1)=2(a+b+c)+4\le 2(a+b+c+abc)+(a+b+c+abc)^2\tag{2}$$
$$(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)\le (a+b+c+abc)^2 \tag{3}$$
I proved $(1)$ and $(2)$ are true but the last one is wrong at $a=b=1/2.$

Answer (score 3):

The following step saves the case of the equality occurring.

By C-S $$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{a+1}\leq\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}\frac{a+1}{(2\sqrt2-1)a+b+c}\sum_{cyc}(2\sqrt2-1)a+b+c)}=$$
$$=\sqrt{(2\sqrt2+1)(a+b+c)\sum_{cyc}\frac{a+1}{(2\sqrt2-1)a+b+c}}$$ and it remains to prove that:
$$\sqrt{(2\sqrt2+1)(a+b+c)\sum_{cyc}\frac{a+1}{(2\sqrt2-1)a+b+c}}\leq1+2\sqrt{a+b+c+abc}.$$

Comment: Nice C-S using!

Comment: I check your C-S step. It gives a proof.

Comment: I think $$\sqrt{(2\sqrt2+1)(a+b+c)\sum_{cyc}\frac{a+1}{(2\sqrt2-1)a+b+c}}\leq1+2\sqrt{a+b+c+abc}$$ is equivalent to $$(2\sqrt2+1)(a+b+c)\sum_{cyc}\frac{a+1}{(2\sqrt2-1)a+b+c}\le 1+4(a+b+c+abc)+4\sqrt{a+b+c+abc}$$By squaring both side again, the rest is proving $$\left((2\sqrt2+1)(a+b+c)\sum_{cyc}\frac{a+1}{(2\sqrt2-1)a+b+c}- 1-4(a+b+c+abc)\right)^2\le 16(a+b+c+abc)$$

Comment: @Anonymous Do you need any condition before squaring ?

Comment: @TATAbox Which condition?

Comment: @Anonymous A>B <=> A^2>B^2 ?

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg Could you please give more detail?

Comment: Did you try LM ?

Answer (score 1):

**Proof.**

WLOG, assume that $a \ge b \ge c$.

Let $Q := a + b + c + abc$. We have
\begin{align*}
 &1 + 2\sqrt{a + b + c + abc} - \sqrt{a+1} - \sqrt{b + 1} - \sqrt{c+1}\\[6pt]
 ={}& (\sqrt{Q} - \sqrt{a + 1})
 + (\sqrt{Q} - \sqrt{b + 1}) - (\sqrt{1 + c} - 1)\\[6pt]
 ={}& \frac{b + c + abc - 1}{\sqrt{Q} + \sqrt{a + 1}} + \frac{a + c + abc - 1}{\sqrt{Q} + \sqrt{b + 1}} - \frac{c}{\sqrt{1 + c} + 1} \\[6pt]
 \ge{}& \frac{b + c + abc - 1}{\sqrt{Q} + \sqrt{a + 1}} + \frac{a + c + abc - 1}{\sqrt{Q} + \sqrt{a + 1}} - \frac{c}{1 + 2c/5 + 1}\tag{1}\\[6pt]
 ={}& \frac{a + b + 2c + 2abc - 2}{\sqrt{Q} + \sqrt{a + 1}} - \frac{c}{1 + 2c/5 + 1}\\[6pt]
 \ge{}& \frac{a + b + 2c + 2abc - 2}{\sqrt{2(Q + a + 1)}} - \frac{c}{1 + 2c/5 + 1} \tag{2}\\[6pt]
 \ge{}& \frac{a + b + 2c + 2abc - 2}{\frac16[2(Q + a + 1) + 9]} - \frac{c}{1 + 2c/5 + 1} \tag{3}.
\end{align*}
Explanation:
(1): $a + c + abc - 1 = a + c + abc - (ab + bc + ca) = (1 - b)(a + c - ac)\ge 0$,   and $\sqrt{1 + c} \ge 1 + 2c/5$.
(2): $a + b + 2c + 2abc - 2 \ge 0$, <sup>1)</sup> and $\sqrt{u} + \sqrt{v} \le \sqrt{2(u+v)}$.
(3): $\sqrt{u} \le \frac{u + 9}{6}$ (by AM-GM).

It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{a + b + 2c + 2abc - 2}{\frac16[2(a + b + c + abc + a + 1) + 9]} - \frac{c}{1 + 2c/5 + 1} \ge 0$$
or
$$ \left( 14\,ab+14 \right) {c}^{2}+ \left( 120\,ab-8\,a+2\,b+41
\right) c+60(a + b - 2)
\ge 0. \tag{4}$$
(4) is true (for all $a \ge b \ge c \ge 0$ with $ab + bc + ca = 1$) which is verified by *Mathematica* - a Computer Algebra System (CAS). My proof below is not nice.

Let $t = a - b \ge 0, s = b - c\ge 0$ (so, $a = c + s + t, b = c + s$).
From $ab + bc + ca = 1$, we have $3c^2 + 4cs + 2ct + s^2 + st = 1$ which gives
$t = \frac{1 - 3c^2 - 4cs - s^2}{2c + s}$.

Plugging $t = \frac{1 - 3c^2 - 4cs - s^2}{2c + s}$ into (4), it suffices to prove that
\begin{align*}
 &\left( -14\,{c}^{3}-120\,{c}^{2}+2\,c+60 \right) {s}^{2}+ \left( -28
 \,{c}^{4}-240\,{c}^{3}+42\,{c}^{2}+281\,c-120 \right) s\\[6pt]
 &\qquad -14\,{c}^{5}-
 120\,{c}^{4}+54\,{c}^{3}+262\,{c}^{2}-248\,c+60\\[6pt]
 &\ge 0. \tag{5}
\end{align*}
We claim that (5) is true for all $s \ge 0$ and $0 \le c \le 2/3$. Indeed, letting $c = \frac23 \cdot \frac{1}{1 + u}$ for $u\ge 0$,
it suffices to prove that, for all $s, u \ge 0$,
$$A s^2 + Bs + C \ge 0$$
where
\begin{align*}
 A &:=  7290\,{u}^{5}+36612\,{u}^{4}+67068\,{u}^{3}+53928\,{u}^{2}+
 16650\,u+468,\\
 B &:= -14580\,{u}^{5}-50139\,{u}^{4}-
 52488\,{u}^{3}-11070\,{u}^{2}+6996\,u+1137,\\
 C &:= 7290\,{u}^{5}+
 16362\,{u}^{4}+6696\,{u}^{3}-3240\,{u}^{2}-450\,u+190.
\end{align*}
It is easy to prove that $C > 0$.
We only need to prove the case that $B < 0$
which implies $u > \frac14$.
We have
\begin{align*}
 &4AC - B^2\\
  ={}& 81\left( 1+u \right) ^{4}\\
 & \times ( 1020600{u}^{5}+2123415{u}^{4}+962388{u}^{3}-145710
 {u}^{2}-4308u-11569) \\
 \ge{}& 0
\end{align*}
where we use $1020600{u}^{5}+2123415{u}^{4}+962388{u}^{3}-145710
{u}^{2}-4308u-11569 > 0$ for all $u > 1/4$.

We are done.

---

**Footnotes.**

<sup>1) Let $p := a + b$. If $p \ge 2$, clearly $a + b + 2c + 2abc - 2 \ge 0$. If $p < 2$, we have
$$a + b + 2c + 2abc - 2
= p + 2\cdot \frac{1 - (ab)^2}{p} - 2
\ge p + 2\cdot \frac{1 - (p^2/4)^2}{p} - 2\ge 0.$$</sup>

Comment: Beautiful solution! +1

Comment: @TATAbox However, I don't have a simple proof of (4) for the case $a + b < 2$.

Comment: Now, it's more obvious

Comment: I hope there is a simpler solution.

Comment: @TATAbox For some similar problems, the C-S or Holder can eliminate the root sign, however the problems are still complicated. Perhaps some tricky way exists. But for tricky way solution, it is hard for me. Calvin Lin said, "Wow, this appears crazy to me / hard to motivate why we should do that."

Comment: Btw, have you check $\Delta_{c}<0$  for $(4)$?

Comment: @TATAbox Not the case. We need to discuss cases.

Comment: @RiverLi I've already upvoted your answer. Could you prove more detail "The left is smooth." ?

Comment: @Inequality Thanks. I will complete the proof soon.